# Paypal one BuyNow button for entire website

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

I have a website with 200 items listed on a separate landing pages. I want to provide BuyNow button for all these 200 items. I do not want to create a individual "BuyNow" button. Instead, when user clicks on any of these BuyNow button it should only pass item name & item value & complete the transaction. How to do it?

Since website will grow to more than 1000 items, it will not be feasible to create separate buy now button for each item via paypal account. I need to create only One Single "BuyNow" button which I can copy on each page and depending upon item listed on the page, it should show item name & item value so that user can proceed for checkout. Its similar like Fiverr. Appreciate anyhelp in this regard.

Comment: What have you already tried? Putting on existing code might aid in getting help as a generic "How do I do this..." doesn't demonstrate any attempt at resolving your problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but not practical. Buy Now button is intend for checking out only ONE individual item.

If your website will grow until 1000 items, it is recommended that you look at other kind of solutions, which involves programming knowledge. We have vast amount of options, one of the popular integration is using our PayPal Classic API.

To get started and explore, check out https://developer.paypal.com/